# Can Android Studio And Unity3d runs on one Operating System?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, sdk

I have been working on unity3d since 2017 before that i installed android studio for game developing but after research i saw unity3d which is been widely used for 2d and 3d game development. I installed the unity and when i developed my first 2d game and was releasing it ,  got an error that **unity3d need's DeUpgraded SDK**.When i downloaded the deupgraded SDK ,then it worked.

After a week i was opening **Android studio got error that you need to upgrade the SDK**.So i got annoyed and uninstalled Android Studio from my system and started using unity3d.

Now when i need android studio want to learn Application development so i was thinking that i can't run both on one Operating System.

**SDK Version** which i am using is : **4.10.0**

**Is there any solution ,that both platforms Android Studio and Unity3d can be run on one operating system?**

Comment: Please add the exact version of the Android SDK you are using and Unity version, include any error messages as well.

Comment: You can specify path to another version of SDK in Unity. You can have 2 folders with 2 versions of Android SDKs and point Unity to use the older version. Anyway there should be no problems using same version for AS and Unity. You need to show your error as Mosbah wrote.